# With access to Active Directory, can I get an object GUID for a user from an username/email address alone?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

**Background**

I've been experimenting with active directory access in C# to find out how to connect/validate credentials in various ways. At the bottom of this answer I've included some code snippets to give an idea of what I've done, maybe this can be built upon to fulfill my aim.

**Main Aim**

If I have valid credentials for connecting to an Active Directory, can I take an string representing a username/email address (assuming it exists in the `userPrincipalName` or similar field), and get back the `objectGUID`?

Or do I need to take other things into account like: the permissions those credentials have to search other users; knowledge of the structure of different ADs; if `userPrincipalName` is the correct field to search?

**Code Snippets (experimental beginnings, not fully functional for my aim)**

```
var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, hostname);
var serverId = new LdapDirectoryIdentifier(hostname);
var connection = new LdapConnection(serverId, credentials);
try
{
    connection.Bind();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //error
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    connection.Dispose();
    return;
}
//success
```

---

```
var dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://{0}/{1}", hostname, baseDn), username, password);
var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(dirEntry)
{
    Filter = "(&(&(objectClass=user)(objectClass=person)))"
};
var resultCollection = searcher.FindAll();
searcher.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with `DirectorySeacher`. You just need a proper query, and a few other tweaks.

1. Modify the `Filter` so you find what you're looking for.

   a. If you have the email address:

   - `(&(objectClass=user)(objectClass=person)(mail=email@example.com))`
   - Or, `(&(objectClass=user)(objectClass=person)(proxyAddresses=smtp:email@example.com))` (this will match against secondary email addresses too)

   b. If you have a username, it depends which username you have.

   - User Principal Name: `(&(objectClass=user)(objectClass=person)(userPrincipalName=username@example.com))`
   - What is normally called the "username", which is often formatted like DOMAIN\username: `(&(objectClass=user)(objectClass=person)(sAMAccountName=myusername))`
2. Use [`DirectorySeacher.PropertiesToLoad`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.propertiestoload?view=netframework-4.8). If you don't, it will retrieve *every attribute that has a value*, which is just wasted network traffic.
3. You don't need to dispose the `DirectorySearcher`, but you do need to dispose `resultCollection` since [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findall?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) says you can end up with a memory leak if you leave it up to garbage collection.

So, assuming you have the `userPrincipalName`, you would have something like this:

```cs
var userToLookFor = "username@example.com";
var dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://{0}/{1}", hostname, baseDn), username, password);
var searcher = new DirectorySearcher(dirEntry)
{
    Filter = $"(&(objectClass=user)(objectClass=person)(userPrincipalName={userToLookFor}))",
    SizeLimit = 1 //we're only looking for one account
};
searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectGuid");

using (var resultCollection = searcher.FindAll())
{
    if (resultCollection.Count == 1)
    {
        var userGuid = new Guid((byte[]) resultCollection[0].Properties["objectGuid"][0]);
    }
    else
    {
        //the account was not found - do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: Works a charm, thanks. Had to change `primaryMembers` to `resultCollection` but I guess that was just a typo.